# Getting error `Barcode Engine assembly not found` Leadtools

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, leadtools-sdk

Getting error `Barcode Engine assembly not found`

when trying to implement example "BarcodeReader_ReadBarcodeExample4()" in following link

https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/ba/leadtools.barcode~leadtools.barcode.barcodereader~readbarcode(rasterimage,logicalrectangle,barcodesymbology[],barcodereadoptions[]).html

Any idea?

[image: I added following Dlls in my project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you are missing a reference DLL that needs to be present alongside your program's executable in order for the demo application to function correctly.

The example you mentioned deals with UPC barcode symbologies. This means you will at least need Leadtools.Barcode.OneD.dll in addition to the assemblies you already included.

Also, if you try to load or save images, you will need to add references to file format codecs. For example, if you're going to work with PNG files, you must add Leadtools.codecs.png.dll.

You can refer to the following help page in our documentation to see which assemblies you would specifically need:
https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19m/dh/to/filestobeincludedwithyourapplication.html

Note that if you build one of the demo applications that ship with the toolkit, it normally outputs the EXE to the Bin folder where all the assemblies are located. This helps you avoid reference problems during development, but when you deploy your program, you must prepare a list of files you need and include them in your deployment.

If you are still facing problems getting this code to work, feel free to contact LEADTOOLS support by email (support@leadtools.com) or by Live Chat through our website.